# Like clause not working with int column in slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

Slick doesn't seem to support like clauses on int columns. The following code where Status.code is of int type doesn't seem to work. Would there be a workaround for this?

```
val query = for {
  s <- Status if s.code like "1%"
} yield (s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your Status class definitation .If code is type column[Int] your code should be giving error as like works on column[string].

The below snippet works for doing a like on integer field.

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
    def name = column[String]("NAME")
    def status = column[Int]("STATUS")
    def * = (name,status) 
}
```

This is data insert and querying part

```
coffees ++= Seq(
        ("Colombian",         101),
        ("French_Roast",       49),
        ("Espresso",          150),
        ("Colombian_Decaf",   101),
        ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49)
      ) 

for( coffee <- coffees if coffee.status.asColumnOf[String] like "1%" ) 
    println(coffee)
```